# Trouble auto-configuring log4j 2 from YAML file

Tags: java, build.gradle, log4j2

This is my application code. When it is run, only the error string is logged. I can see the yaml file copied into the build/resources folder. I'm not able to diagnose why the auto-configuration isn't working even though I've followed the naming convention and placed the yaml file in the proper place.

```
public class App {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.trace("Entering application.");
        logger.error("Some error");
        logger.trace("Exiting application.");
    }
}
```

My build.gradle looks like this.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'groovy'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.13.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.13.1'


    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.0-jre'
    testImplementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.5.7'
    testImplementation 'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.3-groovy-2.5'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

application {
    mainClassName = 'myapp.App'
}
```

I've put the log4j2.yaml file under src/main/resources.

```
Configuration:
  status: warn
  name: YAMLConfigTest
  properties:
    property:
      name: filename
      value: target/test-yaml.log
  thresholdFilter:
    level: debug
  appenders:
    Console:
      name: STDOUT
      PatternLayout:
        Pattern: "%m%n"
    File:
      name: File
      fileName: ${filename}
      PatternLayout:
        Pattern: "%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n"
      Filters:
        ThresholdFilter:
          level: error

  Loggers:
    logger:
      -
        name: org.apache.logging.log4j.test1
        level: debug
        additivity: false
        ThreadContextMapFilter:
          KeyValuePair:
            key: test
            value: 123
        AppenderRef:
          ref: STDOUT
      -
        name: org.apache.logging.log4j.test2
        level: debug
        additivity: false
        AppenderRef:
          ref: File
    Root:
      level: debug
      AppenderRef:
        ref: STDOUT
```

### Update

I re-read the docs and they mention that JSON and YAML config files need additional dependencies to work. I had missed it since I only looked at the initial paragraph and the sample file.
Adding the Jackson Core and Databind dependencies to my build.gradle allowed the config to take effect.

```
  // for JSON and YAML configs
  compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.10.3'
  compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.10.3'

  compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.13.1'
  compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.13.1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loggers are configured at the debug level. The first and third logging calls are at trace level. Trace is more fine grained that debug so those won't be logged. That leaves only your error log event. Since by default the name for the Logger your application is using will be "App" it will use the root logger which will route it to the console.

Comment: I changed the trace methods to debug and it didn't work. However, I re-read the official docs.
They mention that you need additional .jars on the classpath for JSON and YAML configuration. I added Jackson core and databind to my build.gradle and the configuration took effect!

Comment: @karanveer41, can you share the gradle.build that worked? I am having the exact same issue.

Comment: Sure thing. I added the updated dependencies, rest of the build gradle is the same.

Answer (score 3):

Karanveer's solution in "Update" section helped me a lot, thanks (it needed to add Jackson dependency).

But for me it was Jackson dataformat:

```
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:2.13.3'
```

There is description of dependencies that might be required for different Log4J configurations:
[Log4j Runtime Dependencies](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/runtime-dependencies.html)